# Solr 8.6.1 Index data migration from solr 7.2.1

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr8

I'm trying to migrate the Solr index data from one server to another.

Following steps I have performed :

- created collection backup & restored it on another server with the latest Solr version ie.8.6.1.
- created replication backup to migrate the data to another server.

While restoring replication I got error like :

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "restorestatus":{
    "snapshotName":"snapshot.redcurrant_2020_data",
    "status":"failed",
    "exception":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception while restoring the backup index"},
  "status":"ERROR",
  "message":"Unable to read restorestatus",
  "exception":"java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Exception while restoring the backup index"}
```

API used while creating replication backup :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test_2020_replica_1/replication?command=backup&name=test_2020_data&location=/bk/test2020backup
```

API used while restoring replication backup :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test_2020_replica_n59/replication?command=restore&name=test_2020_data&location=/bk/test2020backup
```

Note: The core name was different when I restored collection in another server.

Comment: Any reason why you're not [using the collection backup to the data as well](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/collection-management.html#backup)? When you issue the `BACKUP` command in the collections API, that should back up your data as well. Usually there is no need to try to use the old, per-core replication backup mechanism manually as well.

Comment: As mentioned i m using collection backup API  it yields me a 604kb backup whereas the index data size is around 4 Gb.
While restoring using collection API, it creates a collection with shards but while querying there is no data.

Comment: You didn't mention any of that, but - have you made sure that you've mounted the backup directory in the same location on each of the nodes, so that they can all contribute to the backup? Do you get any errors in your Solr log when you issue the collection backup?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying the same thing and receive the same error unless I make the versions match. It seems copying indexes between solr instances of different versions is not generally supported. You may need to re-index the data in the new instance either from the source or with something like a [SolrEntityProcessor](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#solrentityprocessor).